SUMIF on two arrays from FILTER-function



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L




1
Brand A
Product 01
600

Brand A
Product 01
370

Brand C





2
Brand A
Product 02
100

Brand C
Product 02
650







3
Brand A
Product 02
300

Brand C
Product 01
390

Product 02
200
Product 02
650


4
Brand B
Product 01
400





Product 02
800
Product 01
390


5
Brand B
Product 03
500





Product 04
900




6
Brand C
Product 02
200





Product 01
700




7
Brand C
Product 02
800











8
Brand C
Product 04
900











9
Brand C
Product 01
700





Product 02
350




10
Brand D
Product 03
250





Product 04
900




11
Brand D
Product 03
460





Product 01
310




12
Brand D
Product 04
690













In the table above I have two different lists:
List A Column A:C 
List B Column E:G 
In Range I3:J6 and Range K3:L4 I filter these two lists based on the criteria in Cell I1 using the following formulas:
Cell I3 =CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A1:C12,A1:A12=I1),2,3) 
Cell K3 =CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(E1:G12,E1:E12=I1),2,3)

All this works fine.

Now my target is the list in Range I9:J11. 
The list uniquely displays all products from the filtered list A in Range I3:J6 and subtracts the corresponding values per product from the filtered list B in Range K3:L4.
I know I could do this by applying the UNIQUE function and the SUMIF function on the existing results in the Range I3:J6 and Range K3:L4. 
However, I would prefer to have a solution in which I do not need Range I3:J6 and Range K3:L4. 
Instead the list in Range I9:J11 should be displayed without the "helper ranges".
Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Note:

List B will never contain values that do not exist in List A. Neither for brand nor for product. 

List B can also contain multiple times the same product per brand. It is not always unique. For example it can happen that Product 02 appears x-times per Brand C.



Not an answer to your question, but combining your previous and this question: =LET(a,A1:C12,b,E1:G4,c,CHOOSECOLS,l,LAMBDA(x,y,@LOOKUP(x,c(b,1,y))),DROP(GROUPBY(c(a,2),c(a,2,2,3),HSTACK(LAMBDA(x,l(x,2)),LAMBDA(x,l(x,3)),SUM),,0,,c(a,1)="Brand C"),1))

GROUPBY() may be simpler way. Try-
=LET(x,VSTACK(HSTACK(E1:F3,G1:G3*(-1)),A1:C12),GROUPBY(CHOOSECOLS(x,2),CHOOSECOLS(x,3),SUM,0,0,,CHOOSECOLS(x,1)=I1))

You may also try-
=LET(p,UNIQUE(VSTACK(FILTER(B:B,A:A=I1),FILTER(F:F,E:E=I1))),
HSTACK(p,MAP(p,LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,x,A:A,I1)-SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,x,E:E,I1)))))



With TRIMRANGE() kind of : =LET(a, VSTACK(A.:.C,HSTACK(E.:.F,-G.:.G)),GROUPBY(INDEX(a,,2),TAKE(a,,-1),SUM,,0,,TAKE(a,,1)=I1))

You could also use ETA for CHOOSECOLS: =LET(x,VSTACK(HSTACK(E1:F3,G1:G3*(-1)),A1:C12),c,CHOOSECOLS,GROUPBY(c(x,2),c(x,3),SUM,0,0,,c(x,1)=I1))

@MayukhBhattacharya Unfortunately, I do not have access to TRIMRANGE() as I am not on BETA channel. Waiting for releasing to current pre-view channel.

@P.b Interesting. I didn't think like this. Its new to me. Thank you for tips.

This formula solves the task:
=LET(
  r,VSTACK(
    FILTER(B1:C12,A1:A12=I1,{"",0}),
    HSTACK(FILTER(F1:F3,E1:E3=I1,""),-FILTER(G1:G3,E1:E3=I1,0))
  ),
  _c1,TAKE(r,,1),_c2,TAKE(r,,-1),u,UNIQUE(_c1),
  HSTACK(u,MAP(u,LAMBDA(v,SUM(_c2*(_c1=v)))))
)


The idea is to negate values of the second range then union both range and sum by the product.
The formula can be simplified using the new GROUPBY function which is still not available for me.

For those who do have it available to them: everything from u,UNIQUE through to the end of the HSTACK(…) can be replaced by GROUPBY(TAKE(r,, 1), TAKE(r,, -1), SUM, 0, 0)

@Chronocidal Thank you! I always use documentation but would not like to provide the not tested solution.

Again, just a bit of puzzling:

Formula in I3:
=LET(x,VSTACK,GROUPBY(x(B.:.B,F.:.F),x(C.:.C,-G.:.G),SUM,,0,,x(A.:.A,E.:.E)=I1))


The formula in E6
=LET(filt1,FILTER(A1:C12,A1:A12=I1),
filt2,FILTER(E1:G3,E1:E3=I1),
sumx1,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(filt1,2)),
sumpr1,BYROW(sumx1,LAMBDA(a,SUMPRODUCT(IF(CHOOSECOLS(filt1,2)=a,CHOOSECOLS(filt1,3),0)))),
sumpr2,BYROW(sumx1,LAMBDA(a,SUMPRODUCT(IF(CHOOSECOLS(filt2,2)=a,CHOOSECOLS(filt2,3),0)))),
HSTACK(sumx1,sumpr1-sumpr2))

The first part is based on your trial. In the second SUMPRODUCT sums the values for the unique Product names.

